# Codility error: Invalid result type, Integer expected, NilClass found

Tags: ruby, null, integer, runtime-error

EDIT: SOLVED BY STEFAN
BUT: Now, the only questions left are: Why has the shorter solution such a poor performance (results: 100%, performance: 32%, result: 66%) , while the longer version performs a bit better but seems to produce worse results (60%, 50%, 55%)?

Start of original question:
I'm currently trying the Codility demo test and the problem to solve is to find the lowest integer above 0 that's not included in a given array.
This is my code in two different versions with the same result. The output is right but the compiler throws the abovementioned error, resulting in the test failing. This seems to be a common error on Codility, when looking up this error here on SO.

```
# you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
# puts "this is a debug message"

def solution(a)
  # write your code in Ruby 2.2
  num = 1
  a=a.sort
  a.uniq!
  a.each do |x|
    if x == num then
      num += 1
      next
    else
      break
    end
  end
  puts num
end
```

or

```
def solution(a)
  # write your code in Ruby 2.2
  num = 1
  while a.include?(num) do
    num += 1
  end
  puts num
end
```

results in:

```
Compilation successful.

Example test:   [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]
Output (stderr):
Invalid result type, Integer expected, NilClass found
Output:
5
RUNTIME ERROR (tested program terminated with exit code 1)

Example test:   [1, 2, 3]
Output (stderr):
Invalid result type, Integer expected, NilClass found
Output:
4
RUNTIME ERROR (tested program terminated with exit code 1)

Example test:   [-1, -3]
Output (stderr):
Invalid result type, Integer expected, NilClass found
Output:
1
RUNTIME ERROR (tested program terminated with exit code 1)

Producing output might cause your solution to fail performance tests.
You should remove code that produces output before you submit your solution.

Detected some errors.
```

I really don't understand what's wrong. The array only contains integers, num is an integer, everything is an integer but the compiler says it's NIL. What can I do?

EDIT: The same code runs without errors in the SoloLearn app and on my local machine.

Comment: `puts` has a return value of `nil`. Your method is probably supposed to return the result instead of printing it.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> The output is right but the compiler throws the abovementioned error, resulting in the test failing

Although [`puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#puts-method) generates *output* it has a *return value* of `nil`:

```
puts 123
# 123      # <- output
#=> nil    # <- return value
```

I assume that your method is supposed to *return* the value instead just printing it to standard out.

You can fix this by removing `puts` in your method's last line:

```
def solution(a)
  num = 1
  while a.include?(num)
    num += 1
  end
  num # <- without "puts"
end
```

To generate debug output you could add `puts num` on a separate line before the return value, e.g.:

```
def solution(a)
  # ...

  puts num  # <- prints num
  num       # <- returns num
end
```

or you could use [`p`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#p-method) which outputs the object's `inspect` value and returns the object:

```
def solution(a)
  # ...

  p num  # <- prints num.inspect and returns num
end
```

---

Regarding the performance: try to understand what the code has to do in order to get the result. The "short" solution increments `num` and checks whether it is included in the array. But an inclusion check has to traverse the array (at least up to the matching element). So for each increment of `num`, you are traversing the array from the beginning.

You can speed this up significantly by utilizing [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) for the lookup:

```
require 'set'

def solution(a)
  set = Set.new(a)
  num = 1
  num += 1 while set.include?(num)
  num
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this has a roundabout 100% score. I have to read about set.

Answer (score 0):

```
def solution(a)
 range = (1..a.max).to_a
 (range - a).first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing within the code just remove that lines
for Ex in **Javascript** remove used **console.log**